# Filtering an array....of hotels

Tags: sabre

```
let thisHotel: number = this.$("#hotelsList").val(); // the selected hotel Id value for the one I want..
let hotels2 = this.getModel().get("hotels"); // all the hotels
```

[image]

I have the selected hotel I want in my massive array...

I can see the hotels in the debug by doing specifically

```
 console.log(hotels2.hotels);
```

thisHotel currently = 4 which is the value of one of the hotels.
Loop through hotels2 then the object is under hotels then the specific Id is 4.

I need to get the entire object for the specific hotel where Id = 4

I know there are a number of ways to do this. Some people may use Javascript and some people may use Jquery. What would you do?

Every example I see is always referring to a simple array with one or two values.
This is a more complex object.. I guess these are just the way it works in real life examples.

I'm a newbie so please help me get my bearings ...

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way... if you have better suggestions let me know please...

```
let foundHotel;

//console.log("Hotel Count=" + hotels2.hotels.length);

for (var i = 0; i < hotels2.hotels.length; i++) {
  var x = hotels2.hotels[i];
  console.log("Looping thru " + x.Id + " checking for " + thisHotel);
  if (x.Id == thisHotel) {
    console.log("Match on " + x.HotelInformation.Name);
    foundHotel = hotels2.hotels[i];
    break;
  }
}
console.log(foundHotel);
```

Then I use jquery to prepopulate my form with the info about the selected hotel....

```
$("#HotelName").val(foundHotel.HotelInformation.Name);
$("#HotelChainCode").val(foundHotel.HotelInformation.ChainCode);
```